# Cannot Push from Login in React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redirect, redux

Trying out web authentication in React with Redux and I have the login all set up and working, but I can't seem to redirect to the next page upon login. I've read many replies saying to use this.props.history.push, and now I am getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined". I think I am having a fundamental misunderstanding of props and history. To reiterate, it DOES authenticate and give a web token, but I can't get it to automatically redirect the user to /view-all-cards

I tried putting a Navlink onto the login button, which of course didn't work because it was trying to move to a protected route before the authentication could occur. Many many thanks ahead of time for any help.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { setAuthenticationHeader } from '../utils/authenticate'
import { Route, Redirect, withRouter } from 'react-router'

class Login extends Component {
constructor () {
    super() 

    this.state = {
        username: '',
        password: '',
    }
}


handleTextBoxChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
}

handleLoginClick = () => {
    axios.post('*****herokuapp.com/****',{
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password
    }).then(response => {
        let token = response.data.token
        localStorage.setItem('jsonwebtoken',token)
        this.props.onAuthenticated(token)
        setAuthenticationHeader(token)
        this.props.history.push("/view-all-cards")
    }).catch(error => console.log(error))
}

render() {
    return(
        <div> 
            <input name="username" onChange={this.handleTextBoxChange} 
            placeholder='Username'></input>
            <input name="password" type="password" onChange= 
            {this.handleTextBoxChange} placeholder='Password'></input>
            <button onClick={this.handleLoginClick}>Login</button>
        </div> 
    )
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
return {
  onAuthenticated: (token) => dispatch({type: 'ON_AUTHENTICATED',
  token:token})
    }
  }

export default connect(null,mapDispatchToProps)(Login)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, the history property is undefined. It's probably, because you're not using the withRouter. Try:

```
export default connect(null,mapDispatchToProps)(withRouter(Login))
```

For explanation: The history property is only propagated to the rendered component of a `Route`. All other subcomponents should have this value to be directly provided or use the `withRouter`-HOC

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much, not only did you solve the problem but you concisely filled in the gap in my knowledge. You're awesome.